# To set custom error message in sfValidator?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

How to add a custom error message in sfValidator, the form is

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
 'name'    =>new sfWidgetFormInput(),
 'country' =>new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => CountriesPeer::getAllCountries())),
));
```

the validators

```
$this->setValidators(array(
 'name'    =>new sfValidatorString(array('required'=>true)),
 'country' =>new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' =>     array_keys(CountriesPeer::getAllCountries()))),

  ));
```

instead of required, or invalid message i want a custom message(like 'name is required' 'please select a country'). 
I know that we can set custom error message while rendering the form, but can we set it in form validators??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i got it from the symfony-froms book,

```
$this->setValidators(array(
'name'    =>new sfValidatorString(array('required'=>true),array('required' => 'The name   field is required.')),
'country' =>new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' =>      array_keys(CountriesPeer::getAllCountries())),array('required' => 'please select a country')),

));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the setMessage method:

```
$this->validatorSchema['name']->setMessage('required', 'Name is required');
```

Answer (score 0):

as Harish showed above that is the way to go, but there is also a Plugin http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfViewableFormPlugin that will use yaml files to do application wide error messages, and combine that with the I18N mechanism you will have a nice way of showing errors.